# cannot open VSTO from Lan Drive

Tags: visual-studio, vsto

I've one VSTO excel,
if I open the file saved on local drive, it run as expected, right.
But if I copy this file (also all needed files) into a Server Folder I cannot able to open, I get this error:

Why the program run if is on Local and not if is stored on LAN?!?!?
I found on web some supposition about framework, I tried to use 3,7 and also 4.0, into both case the same error.

any suggestion will be appreciate
Thank

```
************* Testo dell'eccezione **************
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateCustomizationDomainException: La personalizzazione non dispone delle autorizzazioni necessarie per la creazione di un dominio applicazione. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Impossibile eseguire la funzionalità personalizzata nell'applicazione perché l'amministratore ha impostato file:///P:/Programma/Revi4_Inventory.vsto come non attendibile. Per ulteriori informazioni, contattare l'amministratore.
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.RuntimeUtilities.VerifySolutionUri(Uri uri)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.GetAssemblyDataFromManifests(String solutionLocation, String manifestLocator, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, CustomizationType customizationType, OfficeVersion officeVersion, IHostServiceProvider interopServiceProvider)
   in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.CreateCustomizationDomainInternal(String solutionLocation, String manifestName, String documentName, Boolean showUIDuringDeployment, IntPtr hostServiceProvider, Boolean useFastPath, IntPtr& executor)
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---


************** Assembly caricati **************
mscorlib
    Versione assembly: 4.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime
    Versione assembly: 10.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 10.0.40820.0
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Versione assembly: 4.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 4.8.4121.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Versione assembly: 4.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 4.8.4001.0 built by: NET48REL1LAST_C
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Versione assembly: 4.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_it_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting
    Versione assembly: 10.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 10.0.40820.0
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Hosting.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument
    Versione assembly: 10.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 10.0.40820.0
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime
    Versione assembly: 10.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 10.0.40820.0
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.resources
    Versione assembly: 10.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 10.0.40305.0
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.resources/v4.0_10.0.0.0_it_b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.resources
    Versione assembly: 10.0.0.0
    Versione Win32: 10.0.40305.0
    Codebase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.resources/v4.0_10.0.0.0_it_b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.ServerDocument.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed and not supported to run add-ins from network locations. Files should be placed on the local hard drive.

The same limitation exists in Office applications - you can't open or attach a file from a network location. You always need to copy files to the local hard drive first.